# AWS ECS Tasks are killed by OOM killer without exceeding memory reserves

Tags: amazon-web-services, containers, amazon-ecs

We have an Elixir application that is being frequently killed by Amazon ECS for being "OutOfMemoryError: Container killed due to memory usage".

We're using Fargate for our deployments, with 8GB ram containers. We have 4 instances running at a time. When the OutOfMemoryError happens, all containers are killed. We track memory usage with AWS & NewRelic, and at no time does the memory come near the max allowable limit of the container. Additionally all containers are killed at the same time. Seemingly it's killing the containers at only 60% memory usage.

What we're trying to figure out is why this is happening & what we can do to prevent these unexpected memory kill events. Even if one container was killed as it approaches 60%, we'd be in a better place than all containers being killed at the same time.

This graph shows the memory utilization (on average) of the ECS application. You can see at the peak it uses about 5GB of memory (blue line), which is well below the reserved memory (orange line). The green line shows the containers (tasks) restarting.

[image: Chart from ECS]

Here's a snippet of our Task Definition (redacted where necessary):

```json
{
    "taskDefinitionArn": "our-task",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "our-application",
            "image": "image-on-registry",
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 8080,
                    "hostPort": 8080,
                    "protocol": "tcp"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": []
        }
    ],
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "compatibilities": [
        "EC2",
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "cpu": "4096",
    "memory": "8192"
}
```

This issue has been baffling us for awhile and causes downtime every or every other day. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hello - can you go to the ECS page within the AWS console and check the 'Available' and 'Registered' value for memory against the container instances for your (default) cluster? And what OS are you running for `image-on-registry`?

Comment: Good morning, on the Tasks tab for the Cluster, it shows each task (4) having: 4vCPU and 8 GB ram. I didn't find exactly "Available" and "Registered".

Comment: The underlying OS is Debian bullseye

Comment: Sorry, are you using the new or old console? If the tasks have recently been stopped, please add the output of `aws ecs list-tasks --cluster cluster_name --region your-region` to the question

Comment: New console, the output of that command just shows the 4 tasks we have running using the AWS ID.

Comment: I'm trying to see the output of `aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster cluster_name --tasks arn:aws:ecs:your_region:account_id:task/cluster_name/task_id --region your_region` as my first guess would be swap but Fargate doesn't support swap.

Comment: We facet exact same problem in our production tasks. Our containers have only a java process. I checked the JVM metric and it seems it is not related to the main process. I guess it is because of some other process. We will contain system process metrics and look if there is any other process consuming the memory. By the way, another guess is about the swap, it seems ECS triggered a swap event when the memory hit %60. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/container-swap.html. I could not get a chance to look deep into this.

Comment: Can you check if your application has any hard limits like XMX , and see if the XMX value is correct based on the container's memory limits. We had run to a similar problem but without fargate so thats somewhat different. Additionally you can use the "docker stats" command to see the real time usage .You also might wanna look at the ""OomKillDisable" flag via "docker inspect" .

Comment: I imagine you've figured your issue out by now or worked around it, but wanted to share one other possibility for anyone looking here in the future. Turns out that if you have a health check configured in your task definition and it is failing (for example mine used curl which wasn't included in the image), ECS will kill your task with the 137 exit code. It is possible to learn this from the ECS dashboard if you look closely, but for me the 137 exit code was throwing me off and I assumed it had to be a memory issue. After fixing my health check everything worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

After we enabled the java [native memory tracking](https://www.baeldung.com/native-memory-tracking-in-jvm), I figured out there is a sharp increase on compiler space.

```
Before:
Compiler (reserved=1621KB, committed=1621KB)
                            (malloc=1488KB #5084)
                            (arena=133KB #5)
After:
Compiler (reserved=18257800KB, committed=18257800KB)
                            (malloc=1488KB #5085)
                            (arena=18256312KB #10)
```

We were using openjdk 11.0.16. With a small search I saw a [bug in java version 11.0.16](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8291919) and openjdk deprecated java 11 exactly after [this version](https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/issues/505). The issue solved after we moved to amazon corretto 11.0.20.